# Securing Soap web service with certificate

Tags: asp.net, asmx, client-certificates

How to secure a SOAP web service, on .Net tech stack (asmx - IIS), using a client certificate?

I may add that there is nothing in `web.config` regarding this web service, I don't know where to add a custom behavior ([Creating .NET web service with client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544653/creating-net-web-service-with-client-certificate-authentication)).

Moreover, the site hosting the web service also serves web pages - if I set "Accept certificate" in SSL settings of IIS, then the user are prompted by their browser for a certificate.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding. But isn't the asmx secured through the certificate thats being used on your IIS(maybe somebody can confirm). So adding certificate and redirecting from http to https should be enough? Maybe helpful [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2016/08/22/how-to-create-an-iis-website-that-requires-client-certificate-using-self-signed-certificates/).

Comment: Web site is in https but I'd like to secure calls to asmx using client certificate (each consumers of the web service will have their own certificate).